# convert n equal length lists to dictionary with unique keys from one list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I have n lists of equal length representing values of database rows. The data is pretty complicated, so i'll present simplified values in the example.

Essentially, I want to map the values of these lists (a,b,c) to a dictionary where the keys are the set of the list (id).

Example lists:

```
id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
c = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
```

Needed dictionary output:

```
{id:[[a],[b],[c]],...}

{'1':[[1,2,3],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]],'2':[[4,5,6],[13,14,15],[23,24,25]],'3':[[7,8,9],[16,17,18],[26,27,28]]}
```

The dictionary now has a list of lists for the values in the original a,b,c subsetted by the unique values in the id list which is now the dictionary key.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Careful about using `id` - that's a python builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
id = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3']
a  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b  = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
c  = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

# add as many lists as needed, here n == 3
lsts = [a, b, c]

for ki, kl in zip(id, zip(*lsts)):
    d[ki] += [kl]

for k, v in d.items():
    # if you don't mind using tuples, simply do this: d[k] = zip(*v)
    d[k] = map(list, zip(*v))
```

The result is exactly as expected according to the question:

```
d == {'1':[[1,2,3],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]],
      '2':[[4,5,6],[13,14,15],[23,24,25]],
      '3':[[7,8,9],[16,17,18],[26,27,28]]}
=> True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IDs = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
c = [20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]

import itertools
d = {}
for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(IDs, a, b, c)), key=lambda x:x[0]):
    d[key] = map(list, zip(*group)[1:])  # [1:] to get rid of the ID

print d
```

OUTPUT:

```
{1: [[1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]], 
 2: [[4, 5, 6], [13, 14, 15], [23, 24, 25]], 
 3: [[7, 8, 9], [16, 17, 18], [26, 27, 28]]}
```